# Make file empty dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is make file snippen:

```
SECONDEXPANSION:

/tmp/foo.o:

%.o: $$(addsuffix /%.c,foo bar) foo.h 
         @echo $^
```

My question was if a target has an empty list and no explicit rule then the next line following a pattern rule, like in this case "the target foo.o : has no dependency list and no explicit rule " then the make will automatically goes for %.o: rule or it ignores. This is what I want to know please explain?

Comment: **Any body help is appreciated because this question had put by an student. Please reply soon?**

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand.  If you gave an explicit example of what make command line you used, what the error output was, and explain what you wanted to happen instead it would be clearer.